# Picasso image caching

Tags: android, image, caching, picasso

I want to download the following image downloading code with Picasso image cache.

```
DownloadImage downloadImage = new DownloadImage(); 
downloadImage.execute(advert.getImgUrl());

private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... arg) {
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(arg[0]);
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection()
                    .getInputStream());

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return bmp;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AdvertisingActivity.this,
                    AdvertisingErrorActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ad-error", "Error downloading image");
        }
        adImg.setImageBitmap(result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

I have several questions regarding this.

1. I want to download more than one image in parallel. If I make repeated calls of `Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url);` with different url values, does this get done?
2. I want to download images in one activity and use it in another activity. Is this possible? How can this be done?
3. If I call `Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url);` more than once with the same url value, does this load the cached images for subsequent calls after the image has been downloaded?
4. If the image download process does not succeed for some reasons, can you make Picasso report you of the failure?

Comment: 1. yes. Picasso will download images asynchronously, so making repeated calls will cause the images to be downloaded in parallel.
2. yes. Enable debug indicators as per [the official site info](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and you'll see a yellow or green indicator verifying that an image has been loaded from disk or memory cache respectively.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've researched some more into your questions and decided that I should publish this as an answer rather than a comment.

1. Yes - Picasso loads images asynchronously so making repeated calls will cause images to be downloaded in parallel.
2. Yes - just make the call as normal and Picasso will handle the re-use of downloaded images e.g. in Activity1, call `Picasso.with(this).load("image1");` and, later, make a call to the same URL in Activity2. The image will already be cached (either in memory or on device storage) and Picasso will re-use it, rather than downloading it again.
3. Yes - see above (Picasso will automatically use cached images where available)
4. This does not seem to have such a clear-cut answer. One thing you can do is provide an image to display if an error occurs while fetching the real image:

   `Picasso.with(context)
       .load(url)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
       .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
       .into(imageView);`

   The 'placeholder' will be displayed whilst the attempt is being made to fetch the image from the web; the 'error' image will be displayed, for instance, if the URL is not valid or if there is no Internet connection.

   **Update, 17/03/2014:**

   Picasso supports the use of a callback to report you of a failure. Modify your usual call (e.g. the above example) like so:

   ```
   .into(imageView, new Callback() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
       }

       @Override
       public void onError() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       }
   });
   ```

In conclusion, it sounds like Picasso would be a great choice of library for you. It definitely makes image downloading very quick and very easy, so I like it a lot.

Comment: That is a marvellous answer and a great help to my development efforts. Thanks a million.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I recently discovered Picasso and it's made my life a lot easier.

Comment: Picasso is awesome but I am completely new to it. Your answer did help.

Comment: @Ellis How to fetch the image as bitmap. i found get method but that method is downloading image every time its not caching

Comment: @Ellis your answer is great, however can you add about disk cachin also ? how to do it ?